# Entity Framework many-to-many relationship navigation properties and ids

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Suppose in the data model there is a many-to-many relationship. How can I set it up so that the list of id's is eager loaded and navigation properties are lazy loaded?

In a one-to-one relationship, I can easily use the ForeignKey attribute to link the id and the navigation property, but I'm not sure if there's a way to link collections. How can I make sure the two are consistent?

```
public class User {
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public ICollection<User> FollwerIds { get; set; }
   public ICollection<User> FollwingIds { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<User> Following { get; set; }
}

public class UserContext: DbContext {
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuiler.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Followers)
            .WithMany(u => u.Following)
            .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("FollowingUserId")
                .MapRightKey("FollowerUserId")
                .ToTable("UserFollowUser")
            );
    }
}
```

I'd like to have the controllers in ASP.NET always return User objects with the two arrays of User Ids.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In many-to-many you don't need this:

```
   public ICollection<User> FollwerIds { get; set; }
   public ICollection<User> FollwingIds { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks I understand that navigation properties are enough to make the relationships. However, I want a list of ids eager loaded with User objects. Do you know how I can achieve that?

Comment: @cltsang well, it depends, you can query them from Followers and Following or you can use Include: `Include(u=>u.Followers).Include(u=>u.Following)`

Comment: but if i understand correctly, to use this method i need to add this to every single controller, including the ones that returning some objects with User object as a navigation property?

Comment: @cltsang it's difficult to say, there are several variants: to add in all places you need, to use repository pattern and add it in query-method, create extension-method...

Answer (score 0):

To make the many-to-many relationship work, you'll need :

```
public class User {
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<User> Following { get; set; }
}

public class UserContext: DbContext {
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuiler.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Followers)
            .WithMany(u => u.Following)
            .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("FollowingUserId")
                .MapRightKey("FollowerUserId")
                .ToTable("UserFollowUser")
            );
    }
}
```

I believe this would work as you wish.